# Sails.js: Specifying query column as a variable in where clause when querying model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I would like to dynamically specify a query column in a where clause while querying a model, is this possible? I have tried several different ways with no luck. If I run something like this I get Logic db error because it is looking for a column called dataTypeToQuery.

```
var dataTypeToQuery = 'age';
var dataToQuery = 21;

User.find()
.where({ dataTypeToQuery: dataToQuery })
.limit(100)
.sort('name')
.exec(function(err, users) {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the where parameters object outside of your function call and then using the array syntax to set the key and value.

```
var whereParams = {};
whereParams[dataTypeToQuery] = dataToQuery;

User.find()
    .where(whereParams)
    .limit(100)
    .sort('name')
    .exec(function(err, users) {
        // Do stuff here.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect answer. It made my job easier for adding the parameters dynamically as per the condition. You can see following single search for multiple parameters :

```
fullCriteriaSearch:function (req, res) {
var city = req.param("city");
var zip = req.param("zip");
var name= req.param("name");
var page = req.param("page");
var perPage = 10;
var query={}
if(city!=undefined){
  query['locationCity'] = city;
}
if(zip!=undefined){
  query['locationZip'] = zip;
}
if(name!=undefined){
  query['name'] = name;
}
User.find({ where: query,skip:page*perPage,limit:perPage}).populateAll()
    .then(function (users) {
       return res.json(users)
     })
```

}

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: If I will give the city and zip value then I can get list of users for that city and zip.That same search action will work for only city/name/zip input also.
In the above code "locationCity","locationZip","name" are the attributes name of User model.